How to say "The future is a steaming pile of horse-sh*t" in Latin?
As the motto for the evil corporation in a video game I've built, I'm looking for the proper Latin translation of the phrase "The future is a steaming pile of horse shit". Various online translators got very confused by the "steaming" part, but dropping the that, I managed to narrow it down to something along the lines of:

Futurum est acervus equus(-um) cacas
Futurum est struem equus cacas
Futurum est acervus cacas equi
Futurum est acervus(-um) cacas equitum

They seem a bit confused about the -us vs -um endings and acervus vs. struem (as am I). I suspect that most, if not all, are just plain wrong. I'm sure there's more than one way to render it, but I'd like one that isn't obviously wrong to anyone who understands Latin.
For various end-game scenarios, I would also like to add "bigger" or "smaller" to the phrase. As in "The future is a bigger/smaller steaming pile...", but I think that's easily done with "Futurum est major/minor...", right?
Can someone give me a decent translation of the phrase? Including the "steaming" part, if possible.
Many thanks!

Puppis definitely does mean "poop," it is just a little unclear to me why you would bring up matters of nautical construction at this juncture …

@SebastianKoppehel Ha ha! Yes, you're absolutely right. That would explain the translations I was getting. I'll edit the question.
